# Android - Layout on phone differs from designer in size

Tags: c#, android, layout, xamarin

Currently i'm developing a mobile application that shows some values (they will never change, so they are saved in a List). When i'm designing the page in the designer with device ***4.7 WXGA*** i have much space to the bottom but on my real phone (Motorola Moto G3) there is no space.

Now i worry about what happens if i deploy the app on different phones (Samsung, etc). I always thought the advantage of creating a UI with something like AXML makes the app "responsive" in a meaning that it fits to the device which it is running on. But why is this not happening?

May someone give me a hint how to archieve this?

Edit:
Here is my AXML Code - for here i replaced the real text with **Text**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:gravity="center">
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:minWidth="25px"
                android:minHeight="25px"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout6">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="32dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:id="@+id/imgLeft"
                    android:src="@drawable/arrow_left"
                    android:layout_marginRight="50dp" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:minWidth="25px"
                android:minHeight="25px"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
                android:gravity="center" />
            <TextView
                android:text="Text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/tbDin"
                android:textSize="35dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/tbDinWert"
                android:textSize="35dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="XX" />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:id="@+id/imgRight"
                android:src="@drawable/arrow_right"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/tb1"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="142dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:gravity="center" />
            <TextView
                android:text="Text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/TextView4"
                android:textSize="35dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:inputType="none"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:gravity="center" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/tb2"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="142dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:gravity="center" />
            <TextView
                android:text="Text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/TextView4"
                android:textSize="35dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:inputType="none"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:gravity="center" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/tb3"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="142dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:gravity="center" />
            <TextView
                android:text="Text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/TextView4"
                android:textSize="35dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:inputType="none"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:gravity="center" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/tb3"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="142dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:gravity="center" />
            <TextView
                android:text="Text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/TextView4"
                android:textSize="35dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:inputType="none"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/tb4"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="142dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:gravity="center" />
            <TextView
                android:text="Text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/TextView4"
                android:textSize="35dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:inputType="none"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:gravity="center" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/tb5"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="142dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:gravity="center" />
            <TextView
                android:text="Text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/TextView4"
                android:textSize="35dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:gravity="center" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/tb6"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="142dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:gravity="center" />
            <TextView
                android:text="Text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/TextView4"
                android:textSize="35dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:gravity="center" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/tb7"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="142dp"
                android:gravity="center" />
            <TextView
                android:text="Text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/TextView4"
                android:textSize="35dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:gravity="center" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: There are so many android devices with different screen sizes & resolutions. If you have a long content like above, in some devices the list will go out of screen. So better wrap it inside a scrollview.

Comment: it's not just the height that makes me problems it is also the width. in the designer there is enogh space to the left and the right side but on my phone the text was near by the edges. now imaging a phone with less width...

Comment: Would like to know why you set 142dp as marginRight. ?? I hope you are trying to align 1 textview to left & 1 textview to right of the layout.

Comment: to adjust the **Text** TextViews from the invisible (background #00000000 - transparent) TextView on the left side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so first you cannot use same ids for views like linearLayout4. Second, correct practise is best practise so insted of creating so many layouts, create header and ListView and then populate it. Weather you have 3 item or 333 use ListView.

Next thing dont use android:layout_marginRight="142dp" like this. Margin and padding should be much smaller and for acheaving efect of streaching items use something like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:gravity="center">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:text="Value"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:gravity="center"/>
    <TextView
        android:text="Text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="35dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

You can paste it to see the result.

Try to practise design in program that u are creating your app. If you are using AndroidStudio it has preview so you can check diferent size of screens.

And for any layout or view if you set android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" it will always fit to the device.

Try creating layouts and view, with different background, while changing height and width so you can see what is happening.

Comment: can you explane what you mean with "create header and ListView and then populate it. "?

Comment: Create one **Layout** that will hold names of the column and below ad ListView. Here is one [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/) that you can begin experimenting with lists in android.

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep in mind that devices have different screen sizes and different densities. Don't set your pixel sizes in px, but in sp for fonts(scaleable pixels). For other things, use dp instead of px

Comment: android:minWidth="25px",android:minHeight="25px... Also your font sizes are in dp, these should be in sp

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle multiple screen sizes by creating layout-ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi. So that any screen sizes is there, look and feel will be the same across all the devices,and also font should be in "sp" and other elements in "dp".

Comment: so after creating a layout for each resolution cathegory (ldpi, mdpi, hdpi and xhdpi) i have to decide in the code what layout is neede?

Comment: depending on the screen resolution, load the corresponding layout

Comment: so after creating a layout for each resolution cathegory (ldpi, mdpi, hdpi and xhdpi) i have to decide in the code what layout is neede?<---------No, you don't have to decide in code, according to the device screen size android automatically pick that layout(e.g if device is mdpi then android consider the layout-mdpi). Only thing you have to keep in mind is that layout name should be same in all these categories. Suppose you have define activity_main.xml layout in ldpi then mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi should also have activity_main.xml.

Comment: @Radinator, depending on the screen resolution, load the corresponding layout<------Correct, .

Comment: You don't actually have to define all those different layouts in my opinion. I always use wrap_content and match_parent in a way that works for all devices, together with scrollview. Except if you want a nice layout on a tablet, i would do that

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need a full-size None-Stretched Image in your aplication with this tutorial you can adapt a image in every device without problem

https://dzone.com/articles/using-full-size-none-stretched

or this other thing if you wanna adapt your app for the type of device or OS.

The static Device class includes several properties and methods that allow your code to deal with device differences at run time in a very simple and straightforward manner:

- The **Device.OS** property returns a member of the TargetPlatform
  enumeration: iOS,  Android, WinPhone, or Other. The WinPhone member
  refers to all the Windows and Windows Phone platforms.
- The **Device.Idiom** property returns a member of the TargetIdiom
  enumeration: Phone, Tablet, Desktop, or Unsupported.

You can use these two properties in if and else statements, or a switch and case block, to execute code specific to a particular platform.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/platform-features/device/

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/56817/how-to-use-platform-idiom-in-xaml

and in this book you can watch a excellent example the use of **Device.OnPlatform** page 58.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/creating-mobile-apps-xamarin-forms/

I hope with this you solve your problem. Regards.